# Activating Scrolling in React Autosuggest

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, reactive-programming

How to activate scrolling using React Autosuggest (like the fourth example http://react-autosuggest.js.org/) ?

I can't get the option to do that in Documentation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually, it was quite straight-forward :

```
.react-autosuggest__suggestions-list
{
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Defining a static height and adding overflow-y to auto was the solution to my problem.

Comment: I would suggest max-height instead of height, so that when there are very less items, the auto suggest will fit to the items.